# socket.io can't handle errors

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to make real time application with node.js and socket.io. As I can see the server can see when new user connects but can't return information to client side or something. This is what I've on client side:

```
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/js/socket.io.js') ?>"></script>
<script>
    var socket;
    socket = io('http://***.***.***.***:3030', {query: "key=key"});

    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        console.log('Client side successfully connected with APP.');
    });

    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
</script>
```

and this is the server side:

```
var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

http.listen(3030, function () {
    globals.debug('Server is running on port: 3030', 'success');
});

io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
    var domain = handshakeData.headers.referer.replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').split(/[/?#]/)[0];

    if ('www.****.com' == domain) {
        globals.debug('New user connected', 'warning');
    } else {
        globals.debug('Bad site authentication data, chat will be disabled.', 'danger');
        return accept('Bad site authentication data, chat will be disabled.', false);
    }
});

io.use(function (sock, next) {
    var handshakeData = sock.request;
    var userToken = handshakeData._query.key;

    console.log('The user ' + sock.id + ' has connected');
    next(null, true);
});
```

and when someone comes to website I'm expecting to see in console output "New user connected" and I see it: [screen shot](http://prntscr.com/cdbipg) and the user should see on the browser console output: "Client side successfully connected with APP." but I doesn't show. Also I tried to emit data to user but it doesn't work too. I can't see any errors or something. This is not the first time I'm working with sockets but the first time facing such as problem. Maybe there is any error reporting methods to handle errors or something? Also I can't see output on `io.use(....)` method

Comment: Can you try removing the auth layer? You're seeing the auth get hit, but not the "The user __ has connected". There's woeful documentation on what fires the "connect" event client-side, it's possible it needs to pass auth first.

Comment: yes that works, but how to keep auth too?

Comment: oh my bad, I need to add `accept(null, true)` after atuhenticating that everything is fine!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to pass "OK" sign just after authenticating to do the next method:

io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
    var domain = handshakeData.headers.referer.replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').split(/[/?#]/)[0];

```
if ('www.****.com' == domain) {
    globals.debug('New user connected', 'warning');
    accept(null, true);
} else {
    globals.debug('Bad site authentication data, chat will be disabled.', 'danger');
    return accept('Bad site authentication data, chat will be disabled.', false);
}

});
```